# Ceph-Ansible lost group_vars, how to retake control of my cluster in a safely?

Tags: ansible, openstack, ceph

I have recently taken over a small ceph cluster deployed through ceph-ansible, however I made a mistake and lost all the group_vars of the ceph-ansible repository.

I tried my best to recreate them as well as I could, but there might still be missing or wrong parameters especially given that I've started with ceph very recently.

Is there a safe way to read all these parameters from the cluster, in an automated fashion ?  I did my best to manually fill as many as I could.

And is there a way to ensure that ceph won't wipe all my pools when applying the configuration, some sort of dry run before commiting to what I've done.

Thanks in advance,
Florentin Labelle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ceph-ansible comes with an infrastructure-playbook called `take-over-existing-cluster.yml`. See the script for documentation on how to use it.

Since this is not changing your cluster, you can try it and check the produced configuration.

Comment: That's how I worked it out. Thanks !